# Installing PES 2013 on ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: intel-hd

My GPU is intel HD 4400, i can play that game when my OS was win 10, but i can't play it on linux 16.04 TS. Anybody know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that windows softwares won't work on linux/ubuntu?How did you try to install the game?What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try it using Wine. It has a high possibility of working, judging from [this](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26766&iTestingId=79131).
PES 2013 has already been tested, but in older versions only. There is a possibility it might not work on newer versions. If so, you are out of luck.

I see that you are new to Linux. Windows executables (*.exe) do NOT run directly under Ubuntu or similar Linux OSs. You need to install 'Wine' from the Software Center.
Even then, many applications will fail to run. But fortunately, we have the [Wine Compatibility Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/index.php) to check if the application we're trying to run has already been tested and if it was a success. Very often, you also get tips to make it work.

So, thats it. You can't just run Windows applications as if they are Linux applications.
Just as a side-note, Gaming on Ubuntu is best done through native clients like Steam, Desura, etc.